# how to judge all callbacks end after a loop

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, event-loop

I am using `node-mysql` to save data, after getting a `pool` there is an event loop running until `pool.end()` called.
I connect to MySQL in a loop, get results in `node-mysql` callback function, I want to know when all connections completed so that I can cll `pool.end()`.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'xxxxxx',
    user: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx'
});

aArray.forEach(function(u) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (connection) {
            var i = connection.query(aSQL, function(err, rows) {
            })
        }
        connection.release();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or just use a simple counter variable:

```js
var conns = aArray.length;
aArray.forEach(function(u) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (connection) {
            var i = connection.query(aSQL, function(err, rows) {
              if (--conns === 0)
                pool.end();
            });
        } else if (--conns == 0)
          pool.end();
        connection.release();
    });
});
```